# Command rmdir in batch script file not working properly

Tags: windows, batch-file, rmdir

I need move and then delete directories where file was located from disk. The structure looks like that:

```
./Export
  /Report_1
    /12345
      /something.pdf
  /Report_2
  ...
```

My code looks like this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd Export
for /D %%I in (%~dp0Export\*) do (
    set "input=%%~nI"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("!input!") do (
        md %~dp0new_reports\new_report_%%a  
        cd Report_%%a
        for /R %%f in (*.pdf) do (
            for %%S in (%%f) do (
                if %%~zS NEQ "0" (
                    move %%f %~dp0new_reports\new_report_%%a
                    cd ..
                    set "id=%%a"
                    echo !id!
                    rmdir /S /Q "%~dp0Export\Report_!id!\"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
@echo Finished ....
```

But **rmdir** deletes only subfolder with ID (**/12345**), but Report_1 folder is still there, but is empty. I tried echo **"%~dp0Export\Report_!id!\"** and it looks ok.

So on the end of the script structure looks like this:

```
./Export
      /Report_1
      /Report_2
      ...
```

and **I need remove folders Report_1 and so on, as well.**

If I copy command to console it works but in batch script it is not working how I need.

Comment: This is _batch_ programming under Windows and not the _bash_ programming on *nix systems. Removing the tag

Comment: Thanks for editing. My mistake.

Comment: 1. Replace `cd Export` by `cd /D "%~dp0Export"`; replace `cd Report_%%a` by `pushd "Report_%%~a"`; add `popd` after the closing `)` of the `for /R %%f` loop; remove `cd ..`. 2. Change the outer loop: `for /D %%I in ("%~dp0Export\Report_*") do (`. 3. There is no need for the `for %%S` loop, just access `%%~zf` instead. 4. Set variable `input` to `%%~fI`. 5. Do not define variable `id`, simply access `%%~a`. 6. Use quotes: `move "%%~f" "%~dp0new_reports\new_report_%%~a"`. 7. Change the `rmdir` command line: `rmdir /S /Q "%~dp0Export\%%~I"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this suit your purpose?

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
PushD "%~dp0Export" 2>Nul||Exit/B
For /D %%I in (*) Do (Set "input=%%~nxI"
    MD "new_reports\new_report_!input:*_=!"
    For /F "Delims=" %%f In ('Dir/B/S/A-D "%%~nxI\*.pdf"') Do If %%~zf Neq 0 (
        Move "%%f" "new_reports\new_report_!input:*_=!" && RD/S/Q "%%~nxI"))
Echo(Finished ....
Timeout -1
```

I have created the new directories inside the Export directory for now, just to keep everything together. Change `"new_reports\new_report_!input:*_=!"` to `"%~dp0new_reports\new_report_!input:*_=!"` in both locations to change to your preferred structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it